# How to best implement going from app drawer to home screen

Tags: java, android, launcher

Hi I'm working on a launcher and I have added on back pressed to the code and was wandering what would be better for going to from app drawer to the home screen via pressing the back button here is the way its setup right now

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```